# React Native: Install the app Failed. How to fix it?

Tags: react-native

I am learning how to use react native to build an app.
I followed the step-by-step instructions for installing react native at https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
Everything is smooth until install something app for android emulator created earlier. The error is as follows:
"5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Code\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`....."
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuWeN.png)
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfcUl.png)
> what should i do to solve this problem. Help me!

I have tried version checking everything, deleting and reinstalling, creating a new project, creating a new emulator, trying a few command lines found on the net.... but nothing works.

Comment: Well , like the error says: You need Java 11 to run this version of gradle. Your current `JAVA_HOME` points to Java 1.8. Install a proper java version and/or update your settings accordingly ...

Comment: I tried changing the address of JAVA_HOME but it didn't work 